# vb.net scan installation folder for rtf documents

Tags: vb.net, combobox, rtf

Does someone know a code so that my program looks in the map where it is installed for rtf documents and show them in a combobox. I am making an agenda.
It can search for "VPA event -" in the title too (that is what all the event names start with). If i have the code to d that then i can use this one to read the events

```
Dim objreader2 As New System.IO.StreamReader(ComboBox1.Text & ".rtf")
RichTextBox2.Text = objreader2.ReadToEnd
objreader2.Close()
```

thanks

Answer (score 0):

Here's the code you can use to load the comboBox. After that, you can use the SelectedIndexChanged event (or other events) to read the file into the rich text box. I didn't test this, but it should be pretty close.

```
dim ss() as string

fPath = System.Windows.Forms.Application.UserAppDataPath
' or fPath = My.Computer.FileSystem.SpecialDirectories.MyDocuments, or other directory
ss = Directory.GetFiles(fPath, "*.rtf")

ComboBox1.items.clear()
for each string s in ss
  ComboBox1.Items.add(s)
next s
```